# Add delay of 5 seconds in JavaScript code befor clicking next button

Tags: javascript, dom, click

I am executing this JavaScript which is kind of self explanatory (I think). There are around 100 buttons on a page with class `button` and I want them to click one by one. It's working fine.

But I want to add a delay of 5 seconds before this clicks next button.

```
var mybtn = document.getElementsByClassName('.button');
for( var i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
    mybtn[i].click();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` for that functionality.

Instead of manually specifying `100` use the length property.

Also avoid using `getElementsByClassName` its not standard. Instead `document.querySelectorAll` is supported by most of the browsers.

```js
var mybtn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
var i = 0;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
     if( i < mybtn.length) {
         mybtn[i].click();
         console.log("Click handler for button " + i + " fired");
     } else {
         clearInterval(timer);
     }
     i = i + 1;
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div class="button">Hi1</div>
<div class="button">Hi2</div>
<div class="button">Hi3</div>
<div class="button">Hi4</div>
<div class="button">Hi5</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to test this? I mean can we add a alert when this code executes a click.

Comment: This will instantly set the timeout for *all* buttons. Therefore, *all* buttons will get triggered at the same time (after 5 seconds). The question was to have a delay after *each* button. You could use `setTimeout(... , 5000*(i+1) )`

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to notice. Ive upadted it

Comment: @Roberthue you can try  above example and see your console

Comment: I was trying your code but it did not do nothing. I don't see any click event in your code.

Comment: For demo purpose, i added only console. Now added click handler in it. You can try now

Comment: Thanks yes, it's working now. I can see click one by one and corresponding log entries in console. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
//var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('.button'); // Not standard
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

function clickButton(index) {
    mybtn[index].click();
    if(index < buttons.length) {
        setTimeout("clickButton(" + (index+1) + ");", 5000);
    }
}

setTimeout("clickButton(0);", 5000);
```

For testing, I added `alert()`:

```js
//var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

function clickButton(index) {
    //mybtn[index].click();
    alert("button" + index);
    if(index < 100) {
        setTimeout("clickButton(" + (index+1) + ");", 5000);
    }
}

setTimeout("clickButton(0);", 5000);
```

Comment: Using `string` inside setTimeout is a bad practice. Instead declare an anonymous callback function

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not standard as well. Not all browsers implement it. Use document.querySelectorAll instead which is supported by all modern browsers.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working on page. I added `console.log( 'clicked' )` in your code and on execution, it gives random number. No other console entry.

Comment: @Roberthue: Something else must be wrong in your code. Why should it log numbers when you just call `console.log( 'clicked' )`?

Comment: Yes on executing it returns a number once like 3438 and then nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function to call the click function every 5 seconds.

Something like:

```
setTimeout(function(){ mybtn[i].click(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Is there any way to test this? I mean can we add a alert when this code executes a click.

Comment: just add the alert call inside the function :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using another library to solve this problem, then I suggest you use Kristopher Michael Kowal's [**Q**](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) library. Using promises by using [**Array.prototype.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), to iterate and resolve promises when they need to be fulfilled.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EbAB5DCwTFDKvvmLIeY6?p=preview)

```
// Query all buttons
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

// Register Click Event Handlers
Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, registerButtonClickHandlers);


// Invoke button click
Array.prototype.reduce.call(
  buttons,
  reduceButtonPromises , 
  Q.when()
);

function registerButtonClickHandlers(button) {

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // display time end
    console.timeEnd(button.innerHTML);
  });

}

function reduceButtonPromises(promise, button) {

  // register promise callback
  return promise.then(function() {

    // deferred object
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function() {
      // set time start
      console.time(button.innerHTML);
      // click button
      button.click();
      // resolve the promsie to trigger the next promise
      deferred.resolve();
    }, 100);

    // promise
    return deferred.promise;

  });

}
```